# Dataset loading error in Python in Jupyter

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as ny

studentPerfomance = 'C:\Users\Vignesh\Desktop\project\students-performance-in-exams\StudentsPerformance.csv'
```

error

```
File "<ipython-input-10-056bf84aaa71>", line 1
    studentPerfomance = 'C:\Users\Vignesh\Desktop\project\students-performance-in-exams\StudentsPerformance.csv'
                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: try: `studentPerfomance = r'C:\Users\Vignesh\Desktop\project\students-performance-in-exams\StudentsPerformance.csv'`

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard slash `/` and not the backslash. It is not good practice to use the backslash to separate folders. I do not know why Windows is still using this as the standard way to display paths.

The problem with the backslash is related to escape sequences like `\n` (new line) or `\t` (tab).

So the solution is to replace als backslashes with a standard slash `/`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as ny

studentPerfomance = 'C:/Users/Vignesh/Desktop/project/students-performance-in-exams/StudentsPerformance.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a string as a path.

Just put `r` before your normal string it converts normal string to raw string:

```
studentPerfomance = r'C:\Users\Vignesh\Desktop\project\students-performance-in-exams\StudentsPerformance.csv'
```

or

```
studentPerfomance = 'C:\\Users\\Vignesh\\Desktop\\project\\students-performance-in-exams\\StudentsPerformance.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is nothing wrong with what you did. I'm also proud of you for not having any spaces in your path!(very unprofessional). The issue is that the backslashes(`\`) in your `studentPerformance` string are escape characters in Python. So Python escapes from the string every time it sees a `\`.

That said, Windows uses backslashes in system paths instead of forward slashes like Linux based operating systems, causing the users extra pain.

The best way to fix this issue is to prefix your string with an `r`, like so:

```
studentPerfomance = r'C:\Users\Vignesh\Desktop\project\students-performance-in-exams\StudentsPerformance.csv'
```

This tells Python to ignore the backslashes so that it does not escape the string.